# Как сделать авторестарт кода python?

Tags: python

Всем привет, столкнулся с проблемой, апи не всегда отвечает и из-за этого вылетает ошибка, как можно авторестартить код после ошибки(кроме конструкции try except, она здесь не подходит)

Comment: Почему это `try`/`except` не подходит? Покажите ваш код в вопросе. Если программа правильно написана, то всегда можно повторить нужный блок кода без проблем.

Comment: Код состоит из 1400 строк, try except, замедляет процесс выполнения, нужно повторять не блок кода, а просто авторестартить код, ошибка-рестарт

Comment: Я даже проверил ради интереса. Взял пустой цикл из `10_000_000` итераций. Если его обернуть **снаружи** в try/except, то **замедления нет** никакого от слова совсем. Если же поместить try/except **внутрь** цикла, то замедление составило `15%`. Ну так оберните где-нибудь снаружи, а не внутри - и не будет никакого замедления.

Answer (score 2):

Создай ещё один файл

```
import tyshachetyrestastrok
import logginig

while True:
    try:
        tyshachetyrestastrok.main()
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(e)
```

Answer (score 1):

Конечно надо использовать try/except снаружи.

Но если формально подойти к ответу, именно не используя try, то, например, обернуть код в процесс, который при ошибке не будет прерывать главный процесс, а результат возвращать очередью, и если она пуста, то рестартовать процесс

```
import multiprocessing, time, random

def work(result_queue):
    time.sleep(1)
    if random.randint(1, 3) == 3:
        result = random.randint(1, 9)
        result_queue.put(result)
    else: raise TimeoutError('апи не всегда отвечает')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    result_queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
    retry = 3
    for i in range(retry):
        print(f'попытка №{i + 1}')
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=work, args=[result_queue])
        p.start()
        p.join()
        if result_queue.qsize():  # OK
            result = result_queue.get()
            print(f'Результат = {result}')
            break
    else: raise UserWarning(f'Не удалось получить результат с {retry} попыток')
```

out:

```
попытка №1
Process Process-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python38\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 315, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\Python38\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "D:\SCR\flibusta\SZADRE2.py", line 11, in work
    raise TimeoutError('апи не всегда отвечает')
TimeoutError: апи не всегда отвечает

попытка №2
Результат = 7
```